# Cleartype for S-PVA panels

Tags: windows-7, lcd, cleartype

I just purchased a Lenovo L220X monitor for my Windows 7 box. There is an older 17" LCD as a second monitor.

The problem is that this monitor is a S-PVA display (1900x1200) and Windows Cleartype which I normally am a fan of is making the text very heavy and slightly blurry. My second monitor is a cheap TN style panel, and if I drag this very paragraph between the two monitors, the cheaper one is easier to read. Google turns up a couple posts that turn up some info about why this happens, but I have yet to see any constructive advice about what to do about it. Turning it off completely is unquestionably worse; I've run the tuner tool and it hasn't helped.

OS is Windows 7.

What can I do?

Comment: As I am using this monitor more and more, it appears to affect some fonts more than others. Particularly susceptible are that are deemed "optimized for Cleartype" 

From MS: "Yes. This version of Windows features new fonts designed to work with ClearType, including Constantia, Cambria, Corbel, Candara, Calibri, and Consolas."

I'm experimenting with alternates now. BTW, helpful they all start with the letter C isn't it?

Comment: @CoreyH:  What operating system are you using?

Comment: @cp2141 Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

You might want to give the Microsoft ClearType Tuner a shot - you can get it on Microsoft's [PowerToys for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) page.

Comment: Windows Vista and above all have already had built-in ClearType tuner and it has much more tuning options than PowerToys' tuner